# generic lambdas in c++14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I'm trying to compile the following code in VS2019:

```cpp
auto moveToEnd = []<typename T>(std::vector<T>& into, std::vector<T>& from)
{
    into.insert(std::end(into), std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(from))
        , std::make_move_iterator(std::end(from)));
};
```

However, I get an error:

> '<' skipping unexpected token/s before lambda body

Note: I'm using a C++14 compiler.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those ain't the regular generic lambdas. Specifying the template parameter list for a lambda is a C++20 feature. The C++14 "generic lambdas" merely let you use `auto` in lambda parameters.

Comment: so what can i use instead in c++14? just a regular template function instead of lambda?

Comment: @NissimLevy a generic lambda, where type of parameter is `auto`, or a template function ,provided your lambda expression have no capture